# Create a sql database from xml file

Tags: java, saxparser

I want to create a database .sql from a dataset .xml. The dataset has this structure:

```
<dataset_news>
<news>
<url>http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-devon-32954905#sa-ns_mchannel=rss</url>
<date>Sun May 31 23:25:49 BST 2015</date>
<title>Trainee dies on Royal Marines march</title>
<desc>
A Royal Marine trainee collapses and dies on a exercise on Dartmoor.
</desc>
</news>
<news>...</news>
...
</dataset_news>
```

I'm using SAX to parse dataset. When I try to create sql database I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ProveParsing.endElement(ProveParsing.java:59)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at ProveParsing.parseXmlToDB(ProveParsing.java:89)
    at ProveParsing.main(ProveParsing.java:74)
```

The error is in the function endElement(...) when I try to set an attribute of a generic News. I cannot solve it.

This is the code:

News.java

```
public class News {

    private String url;
    private String time;
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public News() {
        url = "";
        time = "";
        title = "";
        desc = "";
    }

    public void setUrl (String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl () {
        return url;
    }

    public void setTime (String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTime () {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle () {
        return title;
    }

    public void setDesc (String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc () {
        return desc;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("\nVALUES ('" + getUrl());
        sb.append("', '" + getTime());
        sb.append("', '" + getTitle());
        sb.append("', '" + getDesc() + "'),");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

ProveParsing.java

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ProveParsing extends DefaultHandler {

    private News news;
    private String temp;
    private ArrayList<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();

    private int newsCount = 0;

    public ProveParsing() throws IOException  {

    }

    public String createTableNews() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (`idNews` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n `url` TEXT NOT NULL,\n `date` DATE NOT NULL,\n `title` TEXT NOT NULL,\n `desc` TEXT NOT NULL,\n PRIMARY KEY (`idNews`));\n\n";
    }

    public String createInsertNews() {
        return "INSERT INTO `database_news`.`news` (`url`, `date`, `title`, `desc`)\n";
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
        temp = "";
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("news")) {
            news = new News();
        }
    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        temp = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("news")) {
            newsList.add(news);
            System.out.println ("News " + ++newsCount);
        }
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) 
            news.setUrl(temp);
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("date")) 
            news.setTime(temp);
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
            news.setTitle(temp);
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("desc"))
            news.setDesc(temp);
    }

    public ArrayList<News> getNewsList () {
        return newsList;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XMLStreamException {
        parseXmlToDB ();
    }

    public static void parseXmlToDB() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XMLStreamException {
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();

        ProveParsing handler = new ProveParsing();

        File file = new File("data/dataset_news.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
        InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        FileWriter w = new FileWriter("data/database_news.sql");
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(w);

        String table = handler.createTableNews();
        String insert = handler.createInsertNews();

        b.write(table);
        b.write(insert);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < handler.getNewsList().size() ; i++)
            b.write(handler.getNewsList().get(i).toString());
        b.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using SAXParser, but do you have to? I use xstream for Java - it's very simple. Your News class would simply have to mirror the XML - each property within the class must be named the same as the XML property - and then you could convert it to an object in a few lines. 
Something like:

```
  public XStreamNewsBuilder() {
    xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xStream.alias("dataset_news", News.class);
  }

  public List<News> buildNewsFromXML(String xml) {
      return (List<News>)xStream.fromXML(xml);
  }
```

http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2013/04/xstream-xstreamely-easy-work-xml-data-java/

http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/convert-xml-to-from-arraylist-object-xstream/

Comment: Ok. But the problem is not in how to parse the xml file. I don't understand the error of NullException.

Comment: I solve it! The problema is in the signature of startElement: public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) is wrong; public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) is correct.